# "The maximum amount of data that you can upload is NaN undefined" error is coming on uploading an image using "Upload Media" button in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1, sitecore-media-library

I am trying to upload media using below procedure:

1. Click on "Browse" of Image field in a sitecore item.
2. Click on "Upload Media" button.
3. Click on "Browse for Media files" and upload a new image.

By following the above procedure, I am getting this error message:

> The maximum amount of data that you can upload is NaN undefined.

[image: Please click here for screenshot]

Hence the image doesn't upload. However I am able to upload image in Media Library and then after linking the same to the item but when trying to upload media directly from content item, I am getting the error.

How to solve this problem?

PFB Form tag statement

```
<form data-sc-id="Uploader" data-sc-databasename="master" data-sc-maxrequestlength="-1024" data-sc-executiontimeout="600" data-sc-destinationurl="/sitecore/media 

library/Images/Social/Connector/download" data-sc-filesizeexceededtext="The maximum amount of data that you can upload is" data-sc-timeoutext="The media files could 

not be uploaded. Please try again." class="sc-uploader row sc_Uploader_42 data-sc-registered" data-sc-require="/-/speak/v1/business/uploader.js" method="POST" 

enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <img class="sc-uploader-preview hide">
  <div class="sc-uploader-content">
    <span class="drag">
      Drag and drop files here
      <br>
      or
      <br>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default sc-button sc_Button_14 data-sc-registered">
      Browse for media files
      <input class="sc-uploader-fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" data-url="/api/sitecore/Media/Upload?

database=master&amp;destinationUrl=/sitecore/media library/Images/Social/Connector/download">
    </a>
    <div class="sc-uploader-general-info">
      <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-progressbar progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 

style="display: none;">
        <div class="bar data-sc-registered" data-bind="style: { width: globalPercentage() + '%' }" style="width: 0%;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-data" style="display: block;">
        <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-data-col col1">
          <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-data-uploadingData" style="display: none;"><span data-bind="text: uploadedSize" class="data-sc-

registered">0</span>&nbsp;of&nbsp;</div><span data-bind="  text: totalSize" class="data-sc-registered">11.2 Kb</span>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-data-col col2">|</div>
        <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-data-col col3">
          <div class="sc-uploader-general-info-data-uploadingData" style="display: none;">
            <span data-bind="  text: uploadedFiles" class="data-sc-registered">0</span> &nbsp;of&nbsp;
          </div>
          <span data-bind="  text: totalFiles" class="data-sc-registered">1</span>&nbsp;<span data-bind="  visible: totalFiles() > 1" class="data-sc-registered" 

style="display: none;">Files</span>
          <span data-bind="  visible: totalFiles() === 1" class="data-sc-registered">File</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you have set the maxRequestLength from the `web.config` or you can update it from the IIS.

**Web.config Way**

Navigate to the path: `system.web/httpRuntime` and check if you have an entry for `httpRuntime`. If not, you need to specify one as follows:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" executionTimeout="3600" enableKernelOutputCache="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestValidationMode="4.0" enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

Note that the length is in kilobytes

**IIS Way**

1. Open IIS
2. Click on the site you want to accept larger file sizes
3. In the main window double click ‘Request Filtering’
4. On the top tab right click to see options and select ‘Edit Feature Settings’
5. Now change the number in the field ‘Maximum allowed content length (bytes)’

If it is present, you may need to increase the length.

**UPDATE**

As you can see, the attribute `data-sc-maxrequestlength="-1024"` has a negative value and this is why the above error occurred. So, the issue is with the maxrequestlength.

Comment: Hi Hisham, Thanks for your reply. This entry is already there in web.config with maxRequestLength as 2147483647 which is more than Media.MaxSizeInDatabase setting (500MB). Is there any other setting I have to look into.

Comment: Yeah @Hishaam, I got that particular id under "UploadMediaDialog" source file. What in particular, to check for there?

Comment: Yeah @Hishaam, Where can i change that setting. PFB Settings we are using: Sitecore - <setting name="Media.MaxSizeInDatabase" value="500MB"/> System.web - <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="600" enableKernelOutputCache="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />

Comment: Can you please replace your maxrequestLength in web.config to 512000 and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: Also, check in the showconfig.aspx page if the setting for the Media.MaxSizeInDatabase is really 500MB since for me, there is an issue with the conversions

Comment: Hi @Hishaam, It worked by making both the settings to 500MB. But not sure whether I can change the setting in system.web as it is intentionally set by someone. Is there any way for it to work without changing system.web setting

Comment: The reason i see is that the size you specified is way too much

Comment: Oh ok @Hishaam, will check with team then. Thanks for your time and patience. Spent lot of time on this.